# Download Build Artifacts in vsts not able to get latest build of a specific build definition

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using the download artifact plugin in VSTS to get the specific artifact of different build def using the current build definition.I am unable to download the artifact to my local agent (I installed private agent).

Error below is throwing:

[‎12-‎01-‎2018 PM 01:30] Shwetha Rattihalli: 
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7178634Z ##[section]Starting: Download Build Artifacts
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7385942Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7386234Z Task         : Download Build Artifacts
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7386451Z Description  : Download Build Artifacts
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7386670Z Version      : 0.127.5
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7386874Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7387214Z Help         : 
2018-01-11T07:23:53.7387484Z ==============================================================================
2018-01-11T07:23:55.4791903Z ##[error]Build with id NaN not found for build definition id 6
2018-01-11T07:23:55.4807213Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Build Artifacts

! [image: Download Build Artifacts]

Comment: Can you add the screen shot for how does the Download Build Artifacts task specified?

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT,I have attached the screen shot in the question above.Please help me out..

Comment: I want that the build option should pick up the latest version without entering manually every time.So how can I automate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Download Build Artifacts task, you need to specify the build manually since the task has no such settings to "get Latest artifacts" for now. And you can also follow up the issue [Download Build Artifacts (Preview) not able to get latest build of a specific build definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6076).

If you want to get the latest build artifacts for a build definition, you can use the [**Fetch Build Artifacts**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.fetch-build-artifact) task instead.

This task can get the latest build artifacts from the specified build definition:

[image]

**Note:** you should Enable Allow scripts to access OAuth token in your agent phase.

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks for responding .I tried this option,Now,its throwing different error.Saying Allow scripts to access OAuth Token must be enabled.Please help me out.

Comment: I added it in the end of my answer. You can enable allow scripts to access OAuth Token and build again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marina.Really you helped me.I will accept your answer.

Comment: do you help me on setting up Sonar in VSTS?

Comment: Since it's out of the question, you can create a new question to describe what the question you meet is and what you want to achieve, so that it can be answered more contrapuntally :)