# Get latest artifact from Build Defintion X and use it to produce a new artifact

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am struggling a bit with the concept of azure pipelines and am looking for hints on how to solve the issue:

We have one Build definition that produces a binary artifact "Generator" in indeterminate intervals.

We have another build definition that should run every night, pull some source code from a repo, obtain the "Generator" artifact from the other build definition, execute it on the source and produce a new artifact.

The problem I have is, how can I get the latest build from the other build definition?

Here is a screenshot of my problem:
[image: download artifacts]

While I can select the proper build definition, the Build has to be an actual build. I cannot add "latest" here (tried and failed) but I don't really want to pin the build number.

Imagine the "Generator" to be something that gets updated once in a while and adds new features etc. The separate build definition at hand, which is not related to the build definition producing the "Generator" just wants to use the "latest" generator and to generate something from its own repository that can be published as an artifact afterwards.

I am pretty sure I am missing something and would be glad to get some hints. (Setting *Current build* instead of *Specific build*) actually does not allow me to select the project and build definition that is different from the current one.

Comment: Use versioned packages and artifacts feeds for this. Think NuGet, PIP, NPM, etc.

Comment: @DanielMann would you suggest the same for executable files that have to be run from command line?

Comment: Yes. An external dependency is an external dependency. You don't want your application to cease functioning because a breaking change was made in a recent build of an external dependency. You want builds of *old* versions of your application to be using the *same* dependencies they used at the time they were originally built. Versioned packages solves these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get latest artifact from Build Defintion X and use it to produce a new artifact

It seems the task [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) you are using is not the latest version, like `0.131.1`. When I add this task (My version is `0.148.1`), there is an option `Build version to download` that I could select the **latest** version:

[image]

So, try to remove it and add it again, check if you have that option.

Check [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/6356) for some more detail about this issue.

Besides, if you could not get the latest version, you can try to use the [Fetch Build Artifacts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.fetch-build-artifact) task instead.

Ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221922/download-build-artifacts-in-vsts-not-able-to-get-latest-build-of-a-specific-buil).

Hope this helps.