# Added agentless job to our release pipeline but it fails

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

Added agent less job to our release pipeline but it fails , Please advice

error: 2020-02-11T19:31:58.7824352Z ##[error]Build with ID 321656 not found for build pipeline ID 241

[failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfwUI.png)

Comment: The error says the specified build 321656 was not found. Please check if the Build with ID 321656 exists for build pipeline id 241. And could you share a screenshot of the settings for the down artifact task?

Comment: You can try checking "allow scripts to access OAth token" option of the agent job and run your pipeline again. please check out  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221922/download-build-artifacts-in-vsts-not-able-to-get-latest-build-of-a-specific-buil)

Comment: it worked without "allowing scripts to acess OATH token"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When troubleshooting with @sudheer kumar, we found the build with ID 321656 can be retrieved via rest api and it is indeed exist for build pipeline 241.

We checked the option **allowing scripts to acess OATH token** for the agent job settings, and it turned out unchecking option **allowing scripts to acess OATH token** fixed above issue.

[image]